# How to Assemble HTML,CSS and JS with EachOther

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

http://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3/

In the "See in Action" section you can see the whole code is separated into 3 parts (HTML,CSS and JS). I'm new in working with asp.net. I know I can put css and js codes inside different files and have a web form which contains html and asp.net tags, But really I do not know how I can assemble the codes are shown in above page to get the correct output.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple straightforward example for a way they can all come together:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      /* PUT YOUR CSS HERE */
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <!-- PUT YOUR HTML HERE -->
     <script>
      // PUT YOUR JS HERE
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This way they all come together at one page, and can affect each other (Css can affect HTML, and JS can affect html & style (which means, it can also change the Css).

Note - the only one you really need in an HTML page is the HTML itself. you could add links to other resources you have written in other files instead of copypasting scripts if you already have the files pre-made, which is probably the better, more orginised approach to this - however the one I've written is more easy to understand if you're a novice, and is probably the best if it's your first time trying all these together. Good luck, new web dev, may the force be with you. (:

Comment: Putting script in the head tag is not a good idea as it will slow down the load time of the page, this is because the execution will halt at the point the script will load and if the script file size is large it will take longer time for the page to render. Therefor it is suggested to have the script tag at the bottom probably before the body ends.

Comment: @Novice Alright, I've changed it. Is this also true when you use linking via referances to JS resources?

Comment: Sorry for the typo the Script reference has to be before the  end of body tag it is not valid to have it after the body tag inside the HTML tag.
I am not sure what do you mean by reference to JS resources can you elaborate?

Comment: @novice In case i use referances to outer JS resources, would it be better to put them in the bottom of the body rather than what I'm used to see - in the head tag? edit - nvm, blex explained it in his answer.

Comment: @A.Abramov Both are fine if you wait for the document to be loaded in your script (eg: `$(document).ready(...)`). But if you put it in the head and directly do something like `document.getElementById('x')`, it won't find it. Putting your script at the bottom of the page will prevent this kind of errors.

Comment: @A.Abramov Yes blex is right about the reference to outer JS resource but the prior concern of not keeping script files in head tag is that if file size is large the load speed of the page will become slow. As blex mentioned outer JS resource reference will only be a problem in case you haven't waited for the script to load.
Another alternative to this is that you can put an async attribute in your script tag if you prefer to keep your script files in head tag, this way the browser will load these script files async and will not wait for it to get loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the file structure I usually use:

```
/
|_index.html
|
|_assets/
        |_css/
        |    |_style.css
        |
        |_ js/
             |_script.js
```

And my **index.html** generally looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Why is the CSS linked in the head tag?*

Because I want the CSS to be loaded as soon as it can, so the user doesn't see an unstyled version of my page when it loads.

*Why is the script called at the bottom of the page?*

Because that way, I'm sure the whole document is loaded and parsed when I execute my script.